# How to make Optaplanner plan only from remaining ProblemFact?

Tags: optaplanner

Assume: there is a group of bottled liquid waiting to be split and distributed into a batch of boxes. Each bottle of liquid is different type and different volume. Due to the volume limit of the planning entity (box), each box can only carry a fixed volume of liquid. Since the volume of the bottle is not same as the volume of the box, it will inevitably result in some bottles requiring multiple dispensing to end.

Question: in OptaPlanner, how to continue dispensing an undispensed bottle of liquid to the next box? How to model it?

ProblemFact can not be changed, so I was confusing how to model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - why you made box the planning entity? Does it have some other planning variables in addition to bottle used? Assuming that the link between box and bottle is the only planning variable it will be easier to model box as fact and make bottle planning entity and use PlanningListVariable. That will allow bottle to be poured into multiple boxes.

So, you will have:

- Box as a problem fact with liquid type and volume
- Bottle as a planning entity with PlanningListVariable List to represent list of boxes in which liquid will be poured
- Bottle will have shadow variable which tacks amount of liquid left in the bottle
- Constraints to ensure that liquid types of box and bottle matched and that amount of liquid left in the bottle is not negative, and that box is not overfilled

There is a weak point in this design - you have to fix order in which different bottles used to fill same box (i.e. biggest first or order by id).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).